# How to organize my methods on the UI in ASP.NET [Design Problem]

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns, architecture, webforms

First of all, I know it's a little long .. But I just wanted to make a clear case here .. Thank you all for your advice in advance :)

I've been trying for 3 days to figure out a good design pattern to organize the methods I use at my UI layer in my web application .. and I couldn't get it right!

### What I Have :

- 19 Tables in my database
- 19 Classes each class is corresponding to a table and has properties that corresponds to this given table's columns.
- 19x2 Pages .. the first 19 pages have the proper input controls that allows me to enter information to create a new record in the table by sending it via an object of the class's type.
- the second 19 pages are for editing the existing records in the tables

### What I Need :

- The first type of pages (the first 19 pages) need some helping methods (Ex: Reset the controls, AddToTheDb)
- The second type (the other 19 pages) need some helping methods (Ex: Determine what's the id of the item to edit, Update the database)
- And finally another set of methods that's going to be common between both the two types of pages.

...I've been using interfaces to force the pages to define those methods, and user [this method in the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693246/force-a-class-to-implement-a-method-without-restricting-the-parameters-in-c/5693267#5693267) to give the flexibility in parameters for the specific purpose methods that are sued by the pair of my 19 pages.

P.S: I'm not that good, so if you any "in the first place you should have .." or such kinda advices feel free to say what you see. I'd be glad to learn from you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"In the first place you should have" created a single page for each class that does both the create and the update. Whatever fields are different between the two operations can be made different when you are populating the page. That will cut down signficantly on the amount of code you have to maintain. It will also make it easier when new things are added to the classes, because the changes will need to be made in only one place.

Doing this will also solve the problem about where to put the helping methods.

**UPDATE**

Creating a user interface with a lot of complex state is something that a lot of people have problems with and do badly. However, there is a simple way to do it that will give good results.

The trick is to put all of your UI-state code in one place, and be very explicit about what logic controls the behavior. Never set a Visible or Enabled property (or even a Text property) in more than one place. That way the logic is clear and can be easily changed.

Here is an example:

```
private void UpdateUI()
{
    bool isNewRecord = (contact.ContactId == 0);

    statusLabel.Text = isNewRecord ? "Create New Contact" : "Edit " + contact.Name;
    nameTextBox.Visible = isNewRecord;

    bool isBusiness = contactTypeBusinessRadioButton.IsChecked;

    spouseCheckBox.Visible = !isBusiness;
    bool hasSpouse = !isBusiness & spouseCheckBox.IsChecked;

    spouseNameTextBox.Visible = hasSpouse;
}
```

Then all of your UI event code looks like the following:

```
protected void spouseCheckBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    UpdateUI();
}
```

Or with some explicit state control like this:

```
protected void addPhoneButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    contact.Phones.Add(new Phone());
    UpdateUI();
}
```

Similarly, it is very important that all data reads/writes to the UI happen in a single place, regardless of the state:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
         int contactId;
         if (int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["contactid"], out contactId))
             contact = Contact.Load(contactId);
         else
             contact = new ContactId();
         DisplayContact(contact);  // Only one method to display new or existing record.
    }
}

protected void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    ReadContactFromPage(contact); // Only one method to read the screen.
    contact.Save();
}
```

Clearly, for complex pieces of the UI, such as open-ended lists of things, the display and input code can be factored into many method calls, but the key thing is that all of that complexity be hidden from the higher levels that interact with the page events.

Comment: @Jeffrey .. Actually I did think about it in the first place but it was too complicated for me to implement it, please have a look at the question and the answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688195/use-one-page-for-adding-and-editing-an-item-in-asp-net

I'm not sure, but I'll try to and tell you the results. but if you think a one page for both create and update is a major point, could you please add your thoughts about a good technique on how to implement it as an answer to the question I just referred.

Comment: @IKashef - I have updated my answer to address your question.

Comment: @Jeffrey .. This looks good but some points are not clear to me: 1. Am I going to define the method UpdateUI() in the page code behind file or where? 2. I get that the UpdateUI() hides/shows controls to adjust the UI to the page's current state(new or update) but why is it called when a checkbox is clicked or a phone is added! doesn't it make more sense to be called in PageLoad event (before the DisplayContact) ? .. Thanks for your time and sorry for the late replay I check the answer while I'm working to make sure I get the answer .. +1

Comment: @IKashef - Yes, it goes in the code behind file. Since the PageLoad event happens before the other event handlers, the UI update needs to happen in the other event handlers. The UI updates happen in response to user actions. You don't want to layout the page, then add a phone to the contact, because then the page layout wouldn't take the new phone into account.

Comment: @Jeffery .. A follow up question. Do you think I should declare the Update() method in an interface and let my pages inherit from it or not ?

Comment: @IKashef - I don't think you should create an interface at first. If, later, you find that an interface will solve some kind of problem, then you can refactor it into an interface. The first version should be as simple as possible.

Comment: @Jeffrey .. The interface will simply contain this void Update(); .. so every page uses this interface will implement the Update method. that's all what I'm planning to do .. I'm just explaining how I'm going to do it .. if you think it's still unnecessary please let me know.

Comment: @IKashef - An interface could be useful if you are planning to manipulate the page within a code library. For example, if a bunch of pages contain exactly the same complex logic around some piece of common data. I would not expect this to be the case, however. A custom control would be a better solution to the problem of common complex logic. I cannot think of what an interface would be used for in this case, and things that are not necessary should be left out. If you would like to manipulate the page in a library, though, then an interface would be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a base page class that other will inherit from. If there is common functionality there that can be reused, that's probably a good starting point. No if you are direct editing of tables, since you have like a table per class aproach, then maybe you could use some framework or create a generic edit feature for simplier tables.

Now as an advice, don't overdo the less code is better approach. Nice clean easy to understand code is much more valuable.

Comment: . for the advice about not overdoing the less code approach, I'll take that into account. and as for your advice about base page, It's not my first time to hear about it in the answers but I actually don't have a any experience or knowledge about it except that I know it's an abstract class that inherits from the System.Web.UI.Page
 and I let my page to inherit this abstract class instead of inhering the System.Web.UI.Page. so If you have a more details, maybe an article, tutorial. That would be great! =)

Comment: [Here][1] (http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/041305-1.aspx) is a nice complete article. Actually your base page doesn't have to be abstract, just inherit from Page, the class your web forms used to inherit from. Also it needs to call some of the Page class code, so it won't break basic functionality.